# How to enable parent after on last child uncheck?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have implemented code for enable/disable childs and parents based on user requirement so one of the requirement I have kendo treeview with checkboxes where i implemented below code when child is uncheck enable parent thats what it suppose to do but problem is if i check multiple childs and uncheck any one of them its enabling parent. I want to enable parent when last child gets unchecked.

see code below so far...

HTML

```
<div id="treeViewDisplay4" class="dropdown-menu multi-level" ng-style="nonPersistentProcess.geoLocationStyle">
    <div kendo-tree-view="geoLocationTree" k-data-source="geoLocationDataSource" options="geoLocationTreeOptions" k-on-expand="onGeoExpand(kendoEvent)" k-rebind="nonPersistentProcess.selectedTypeGEO"></div>
</div>
```

index.js

```
$scope.updateGeoLoctionList = function(geoLocation){
        var pos = $.inArray(geoLocation.text, selectedGeoLocations);

        if(pos < 0){
            selectedGeoLocations.push(geoLocation.text);
            selectedGeoLocationIds.push(geoLocation.id);
            //if Global is checked disable all parent and children
            if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
              $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
                if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
                  $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
                    var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
                    var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                      model.assign($scope, true);
                  })
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, true);

                }
              });
            }
            // If a child is checked Disable the parents
            try {
                var parent = geoLocation.parent().parent();
                var disableParentId = 'disabled' + parent.id;
                var parentModel = $parse(disableParentId);
                parentModel.assign($scope, true);
            } catch (err) {
           // Ignore since this happens when a node is selected which has no children 
              }
           //Expand tree on parent check so childs can be disabled.
            $scope.geoLocationTree.expand($scope.geoLocationTree.findByText(geoLocation.text));
            //If the parent item is checked, disable all the children
            if(geoLocation.items) {
                $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location) {
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, true);
                });
            }
        } else {

            selectedGeoLocations.splice(pos,1);
            selectedGeoLocationIds.splice($.inArray(geoLocation.id,selectedGeoLocationIds),1);
            //if Global is uncheck enable all parents and children
            if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
              var getParent = geoLocation.parent();
              $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
                if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
                  $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
                    var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
                    var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                      model.assign($scope, false);
                  })
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, false);
                }
              });
            }
            // If child is unchecked Enable the parent
            try {
                  var parent = geoLocation.parent().parent();
                  $.each(parent._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,childNode){
                    for(var i=0; i < geoLocation.length; i++){
                    }
                  })
                  var disableParentId = 'disabled' + parent.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var parentModel = $parse(disableParentId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  parentModel.assign($scope, false);
            } catch (err) {
              // Ignore since this happens when a node is selected which has no children 
            }
            //If the parent item is unchecked,  enable the childrens
            if(geoLocation.items){
                $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location){
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, false);
                });
            }
        }
        $scope.nonPersistentProcess.geoLocations = selectedGeoLocations.toString();  
    };
```

Config.js

```
geoLocationTreeConfig : {
        template: '{{dataItem.text}}',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false,
           template: '<input ng-disabled=\'disabled#: item.id #\' type=\'checkbox\' ng-click=\'updateGeoLoctionList(dataItem)\' value=\'true\' />'
        }
```

Comment: any chance you an quip up a plunk so we can work on it...

Comment: Sorry can not use plunker/jsFiddle for some reason. If you can help here much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: your code above doesn't help us to know what logic you have used to disabled/enabled.. please put some more code, like this function `updateGeoLoctionList`

Comment: @DionDirza I added code for updateGeolocationList.

Answer (score 0):

I passed selectedItems[ ] to newArray and with if condition i was able to enable parent after last child uncheck.

```
try {
                      var parent = geoLocation.parent().parent();
                      var checkedChildrens = [];
                      for (var i=0; i<selectedRiskGeoLocations.length; i++){
                        var checkNodes = selectedRiskGeoLocations[i];
                        checkedChildrens.push(checkNodes);
                      }
                      if (checkedChildrens.length === 0){
                        var disableParentId = 'disabled' + parent.id;
                        // Get the model
                        var parentModel = $parse(disableParentId);
                        // Assigns a value to it
                        parentModel.assign($scope, false);
                      };
                }
```